# Save audio in caf format to wav format

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I record audio in .caf format and later need to convert it to .wav in order to send the file as a email attachment.  How can I convert the file to wav format in iOS 3.1.x?

The format of the audio:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:11025.0f],            AVSampleRateKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],                     AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt:16],                    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],                  AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],                   AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
```

I am not tied to this format, I just need to be able to record and playback on the device and email a wav version file.

Comment: I have been in same situation. I tried to give it .wav extension in url name, but at other end(server) it is showing unknown file format. I don't think its converted to .wav actually. So any help how you did that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple, just init with a .wav extension.

The answer was provided by Paul Bruneau on the Apple Developer forum:

From the class reference docs, the recorder infers the file type from the extension that you choose. So try .aiff or .aif or .wav

initWithURL:settings:error:
Initializes and returns an audio recorder.

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
settings:(NSDictionary *)settings
error:(NSError **)outError
```

Parameters: url

The file system location to record to. The file type to record to is inferred from the file extension included in this parameter’s value.

Comment: I have tried using this. But when is send this file to server it shows unknown file type.

Answer (score 2):

**The Bad:**

I don't think there is any "automatic" way to do this wit the iPhone, meaning you have to do it yourself - manually.

**The Good:**

It is very very simple to do. A WAV file - assuming your just talking about using raw, uncompressed audio - is just a header you need to stick on the beginning of the audio data. The format is very simple. There are numerous references on the web:

http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html

**The Ugly:**

I am not farmiliar with the source format you are talking about. If it is uncompressed, great. If not, you may need to uncompress it. WAV files also have methods to store *compressed* data, so if your data source is compressed, then you *might* be able to store it as such in the WAV by generating new headers and indicating it compressed as such.

Also - by "compressed" - I mean in any codec other than standard X-bit Y-Channel PCM.

Comment: So very easy then. You only have a single audio channel so there's no question of how the multiple channels get packed in. You should just be able to fillout a WAV header structure with the pertinent information and then append your raw audio data. As you know all the info up front - they're all *constants* - the only variable would be the size of the audio clip. Use a "Compression Code" of "1" (PCM/Uncompressed). There are a *billion* references for this on the web - in addition to the one I posted. Use it, or Google "WAV file format" or "WAV file header" if you want another.

Comment: It seems that since Apple has created a .caf container there should be an API to create standard formats such as .wav and. aif without having to munge the raw data.